# If Conditional for Lightswitch in Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, conditional

I have a section that needs to display a certain block type (heroVideo) if a lightswitch (displayHeroVideo) within it is active. Otherwise, it should display a different block type (heroImage).

How can I write a conditional to accommodate this?

Here's what I have already which outputs both blocks if the lightswitch is active. How do I apply the conditional earlier?

```
{# Start hero section #}
{% for entry in entry.heroFeatured.limit(1) %}
  {% for block in entry.hero %}

  {% if block.type == "heroVideo" and block.displayHeroVideo == "1" %}

  <h1>Hero Video Markup</h1>

  {% else %}

  <h1>Hero Image Markup</h1>

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're close! The way you have your conditional set up now will print Hero Image Markup if either of your conditionals fail. By checking if `block.displayHeroVideo` is 1 on a block type that doesn't have that field, Twig will still return 0. You should only check `displayHeroVideo` when you know you are inside of a `heroVideo` block.

```
{% for entry in entry.heroFeatured.limit(1) %}
    {% for block in entry.hero %}

        {% if block.type == "heroVideo" %}

            {% if block.displayHeroVideo == "1" %} 

                <h1>Hero Video Markup</h1>

            {% endif %}

        {% else %}

            <h1>Hero Image Markup</h1>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This still prints both the heroVideo block and the heroImage block if the lightswitch in heroVideo is active. I'm trying to get it so that if lightswitch is active only display the heroVideo block.

Comment: Will the heroVideo block always be the first block?

Comment: Here's my matrix field setup: http://prntscr.com/7vsvtq

Answer (score 1):

Might be better to just adjust the matrix field itself (upload a video or an image and make an if statement depending on file type).

It also is easier if you wouldnt put the image field inside the "hero" block. This way you won't have the issue regarding turning off the other block.

I would adjust your matrix to one of the mentioned methods above. If you do that you can easily access the light switch and make a if statement like:

```
  {% for block in entry.hero %}

        {% if block.type == "heroBlock" %}

            {% if block.displayHeroVideo %}
                <h1>Hero Video Markup</h1>
            {% else %}
                 <h1>Hero Image Markup</h1>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

This works if you merge the 2 blocks into one (named Hero Block here). It will save you alot of time writing complicated code and also keeps your code clean.